# Mongoose ValidationError (Path is required)

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

i am trying to write a post method in express...for some events planing web app...
created the event model and the user model, passed an id field in the event model...after this my code stopped working...giving me the above error...
i am attaching screen shots

any help would be appreciated

i am trying to write a post method in express...for some events planing web app...
created the event model and the user model, passed an id field in the event model...after this my code stopped working...giving me the above error...
i am attaching screen shots

any help would be appreciated

i am trying to write a post method in express...for some events planing web app...
created the event model and the user model, passed an id field in the event model...after this my code stopped working...giving me the above error...
i am attaching screen shots

any help would be appreciated

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
//Event Model
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   title:{
       type:String,
       required:true
   },

   description:{
       type:String,
       required:true
   },
   location:{
       type:String,
       required:true
   },
   date:{
       type:Date,
       required:true,
       default:Date.now
   },
user_id:{
    type:String,
    required:true
     },

   created_at:{
       date:Date,
   }
});
const Event = mongoose.model('Event',eventSchema,'events');
module.exports = Event;



//User Model
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bCrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   email:{
       type:String,
       required:true
   },
   password:{
       type:String,
       required:true
   }
});
userSchema.methods.hashPassword = (password) =>{
   return bCrypt.hashSync(password,bCrypt.genSaltSync(10))
}
userSchema.methods.comparePasswords = (password,hash)=>{
   return bCrypt.compareSync(password,hash);
}

const User = mongoose.model('User',userSchema,'users');

module.exports = User;





//post Method:

router.post('/create',[
   check('title').isLength({min:5}).withMessage('Title should be more than 5 letters'),
   check('description').isLength({min:5}).withMessage('description should be more than 5 letters'),
   check('location').isLength({min:5}).withMessage('location should be more than 5 letters'),
   check('date').isLength({min:5}).withMessage('date should be more than 5 letters')
  ],(req,res)=>{
       const errors = validationResult(req);
       if(!errors.isEmpty()){
           req.flash('errors',errors.array())
           res.redirect('/events/create')
       }
       else{
           const newEvent = new Event({
               title:req.body.title,
               description:req.body.description,
               location:req.body.location,
               date:req.body.date,
               user_id:req.user_id,
               created_at:Date.now()
           });
           newEvent.save((err)=>{
               if(!err){
                   console.log('Event was added!');
                   req.flash('info','Event was created successfully!');
                   res.redirect('/events');
               }
               else{
                   console.log(err);
               }
           })
       }
  }); 




App is running on port 3000
(node:23844) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
Error [ValidationError]: Event validation failed: user_id: Path `user_id` is required.
   at ValidationError.inspect (C:\Users\Hassan\Desktop\events\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:61:24)
   at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:563:31)
   at inspect (internal/util/inspect.js:221:10)
   at formatWithOptions (internal/util/inspect.js:1693:40)
   at Object.Console.<computed> (internal/console/constructor.js:272:10)
   at Object.log (internal/console/constructor.js:282:61)
   at C:\Users\Hassan\Desktop\events\routes\event-routes.js:69:29
   at C:\Users\Hassan\Desktop\events\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4598:16
   at C:\Users\Hassan\Desktop\events\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:256:11
   at C:\Users\Hassan\Desktop\events\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:468:16
   at C:\Users\Hassan\Desktop\events\node_modules\kareem\index.js:246:48
   at next (C:\Users\Hassan\Desktop\events\node_modules\kareem\index.js:167:27)
   at next (C:\Users\Hassan\Desktop\events\node_modules\kareem\index.js:169:9)
   at Kareem.execPost (C:\Users\Hassan\Desktop\events\node_modules\kareem\index.js:217:3)
   at _handleWrapError (C:\Users\Hassan\Desktop\events\node_modules\kareem\index.js:245:21)
   at C:\Users\Hassan\Desktop\events\node_modules\kareem\index.js:272:14 {
 errors: {
   user_id: MongooseError [ValidatorError]: Path `user_id` is required.
       at new ValidatorError (C:\Users\Hassan\Desktop\events\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validator.js:29:11)
       at validate (C:\Users\Hassan\Desktop\events\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1055:13)
       at C:\Users\Hassan\Desktop\events\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1109:11
       at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
       at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (C:\Users\Hassan\Desktop\events\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1064:14)
       at C:\Users\Hassan\Desktop\events\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2190:9
       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
     message: 'Path `user_id` is required.',
     name: 'ValidatorError',
     properties: [Object],
     kind: 'required',
     path: 'user_id',
     value: undefined,
     reason: undefined,
     [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
   }
 },
 _message: 'Event validation failed',
 name: 'ValidationError'
}
connected to DB



```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
i am trying to write a post method in express...for some events planing web app...
created the event model and the user model, passed an id field in the event model...after this my code stopped working...giving me the above error...
i am attaching screen shots 


any help would be appreciated
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Can you add the related code like model, router to the question?

Comment: added already...thanks

Comment: Can you delete the collections in Events collection and try? becase you added required userId field, but previous documents didn't have this field before this.

Comment: hi ...i deleted the events collection from my collections and retried....still getting the same error: i added the complete error log in the question body for your reference ....thanks alot

Comment: I think I found the issue, can you check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is mongoose Error mostly due to mongoose connection not finding URL for POST or GET API.

1. One other chance is to make sure you have created a `/data` folder inside your mongoose installation location with bin and start mongoose service which is Mongoose and mongod.exe and try with Mongodb compass for checking connection is successful or not.
2. other like check your Mongo connection is connected properly if it is connected or not in DB connection URL.

Comment: hello....the connection is totally fine...i am using mongo atlas ...and all the posts i made before adding the user_id field was successful....the error only started to show when i added the user_id field in the event model and in the post method

Comment: You are correct that null is a value type, but null types are a way of telling the interpreter that it has no value. therefore, you must set the values to any non-null value or you get the error. in your case set those values to empty Strings.

Comment: var newUser = new user({

  /* We will set the username, email and password field to null because they will be set later. */
  username: '',
  passwordHash: '',
  email: '',
  admin: false

}, { _id: false });